# Count records per hour within a time span

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a table with a userID, a startDate and an endDate.
I would like to count hour by hour the number of userID concerned.

For example, the user '4242' with startDate = '21/05/2014 01:15:00' and with endDate = '21/05/2014 05:22:00' should be counted once from 01 to 02, once from 02 to 03, once from 03 to 04, ...

It would give a result like that:

```
DATE AND TIME                   COUNT
-------------------------------------
20140930 18-19                    198 
20140930 19-20                    220 
20140930 20-21                    236 
20140930 21-22                    257 
20140930 22-23                    257 
20140930 23-00                    257 
20141001 00-01                    259 
20141001 01-02                    259 
20141001 02-03                    258 
20141001 03-04                    259 
20141001 04-05                    258 
20141001 05-06                    258
```

How would you do that ?

Well, I tried a lot of things. Here's my latest attempt. If the code is too messy, don't even bother reading it, just tell me how you would handle this problem ;) Thanks !

```
WITH timespan AS (
   SELECT lpad(rownum - 1,2,'00') ||'-'|| lpad(mod(rownum,24),2,'00') AS hours
    FROM dual
   connect BY level <= 24
  ),

 UserID_min_max AS (
   SELECT  USERS.UserID, 
          min(USERS.date_startUT) AS min_date,
          max(USERS.date_end) AS max_date,
          code_etat
   FROM      USERS

 WHERE    (
    (USERS.date_startUT  >=  to_date('01/10/2014 00:00:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
    AND  USERS.date_end  <=  to_date('08/10/2014 23:59:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss'))
    OR  ( USERS.date_startUT  <=  to_date('01/10/2014 00:00:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
    AND  USERS.date_end  >=  to_date('01/10/2014 00:00:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
    AND   USERS.date_end  <=  to_date('08/10/2014 23:59:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss'))
    OR   (USERS.date_startUT  BETWEEN  to_date('01/10/2014 00:00:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss') AND to_date('08/10/2014 23:59:00','dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss')))
  GROUP BY USERS.UserID, code_etat
  ),

  hours_list AS (
   SELECT  UserID, min_date, max_date, code_etat
    , to_char(min_date + row_number() over (partition BY UserID ORDER BY 1)-1,'yyyymmdd') AS days
    , to_char(min_date,'yyyymmdd') AS date_start
    , to_char(min_date, 'hh24') || '-' || lpad(to_number(to_char(min_date, 'hh24')) + 1, 2, '00') AS timespan_date_start
    , to_char(max_date,'yyyymmdd') AS date_end
    , to_char(max_date, 'hh24') || '-' || lpad(to_number(to_char(max_date, 'hh24')) + 1, 2, '00') AS timespan_date_end

  FROM UserID_min_max cmm
   connect BY level <= trunc(max_date) - trunc(min_date)+1
    AND PRIOR UserID = UserID
    AND prior sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  ),

  all_timespan_hours_list AS (
   SELECT lj.*, t.*, lj.days ||' '|| t.hours AS days_hours
   FROM hours_list lj
   JOIN timespan t
   ON lj.days || t.hours >= lj.date_start || lj.timespan_date_start
   AND lj.days || t.hours <= lj.date_end || lj.timespan_date_end
  )

SELECT DISTINCT days_hours, COUNT(*)
FROM (

   SELECT *

   FROM all_timespan_hours_list ttlj

    WHERE CODE_ETAT IN ('SOH','SOL')

  )
  GROUP BY days_hours
  ORDER BY days_hours;
```

Comment: What is the max difference between start date and end date for a user? A month? A year?

Comment: @DavidFaber A week usually :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do something similar:

```
with dt_tab as (select trunc(:p_start_date, 'hh') + (level - 1)/24 hr
                from   dual
                connect by level <= (trunc(:p_end_date, 'hh') - trunc(:p_start_date, 'hh'))*24 + 1),
sample_data as (select 4242 usr, to_date('21/05/2015 01:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('21/05/2015 05:22:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date from dual union all
                select 4243 usr, to_date('20/05/2015 18:32:42', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('21/05/2015 01:36:56', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date from dual union all
                select 4244 usr, to_date('21/05/2015 07:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, null end_date from dual)
select   to_char(dt.hr, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24-')||to_char(dt.hr + 1/24, 'hh24') date_and_time,
         count(sd.usr) cnt
from     dt_tab dt
         left outer join sample_data sd on (dt.hr < nvl(sd.end_date, :p_end_date) and dt.hr >= sd.start_date)
group by to_char(dt.hr, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24-')||to_char(dt.hr + 1/24, 'hh24')
order by date_and_time;

:p_start_date := 20/05/2015 08:00:00
:p_end_date := 21/05/2015 08:00:00

DATE_AND_TIME    CNT
---------------- ---
20/05/2015 08-09   0
20/05/2015 09-10   0
20/05/2015 10-11   0
20/05/2015 11-12   0
20/05/2015 12-13   0
20/05/2015 13-14   0
20/05/2015 14-15   0
20/05/2015 15-16   0
20/05/2015 16-17   0
20/05/2015 17-18   0
20/05/2015 18-19   0
20/05/2015 19-20   1
20/05/2015 20-21   1
20/05/2015 21-22   1
20/05/2015 22-23   1
20/05/2015 23-00   1
21/05/2015 00-01   1
21/05/2015 01-02   1
21/05/2015 02-03   1
21/05/2015 03-04   1
21/05/2015 04-05   1
21/05/2015 05-06   1
21/05/2015 06-07   0
21/05/2015 07-08   1
21/05/2015 08-09   0
```

(depending on how your time period start and end dates are configured, you might want to change from using bind variables - eg. use the min/max dates in your table, etc)

---

The above works when I run it in Toad. For something that works in SQL*Plus, or when you run it as a script (e.g. in Toad), the below should work:

```
variable p_start_date varchar2(20)
variable p_end_date varchar2(20)

exec :p_start_date := '20/05/2015 08:00:00';
exec :p_end_date := '21/05/2015 08:00:00';


with dt_tab as (select trunc(to_date(:p_start_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh') + (level - 1)/24 hr
                from   dual
                connect by level <= (trunc(to_date(:p_end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh') - trunc(to_date(:p_start_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh'))*24 + 1),
sample_data as (select 4242 usr, to_date('21/05/2015 01:15:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('21/05/2015 05:22:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date from dual union all
                select 4243 usr, to_date('20/05/2015 18:32:42', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, to_date('21/05/2015 01:36:56', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date from dual union all
                select 4244 usr, to_date('21/05/2015 07:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date, null end_date from dual)
select   to_char(dt.hr, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24-')||to_char(dt.hr + 1/24, 'hh24') date_and_time,
         count(sd.usr) cnt
from     dt_tab dt
         left outer join sample_data sd on (dt.hr < nvl(sd.end_date, to_date(:p_end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) and dt.hr >= sd.start_date)
group by to_char(dt.hr, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24-')||to_char(dt.hr + 1/24, 'hh24')
order by date_and_time;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
Indeed, I'll always have someone present and I don't care about the periods where none is present, so i'll skip the left join. But I don't understand. What would you put in the group by then ?

Comment: Oh, hmm, upon thinking about it, yes, you would need to have something to generate the rows. I'll update my answer to remove that bit.

Comment: I have a problem with the code you provided.
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional code that you can run via sql*plus or a script. I would imagine that if this is going to go in production PL/SQL code, you'd want to have parameters (of DATE datatype, hopefully!) that you'd use in place of the :p_start_date and :p_end_date variables in my original code.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll adapt what you've done in my code !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function [TRUNC(date,[fmt])](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) like this:

```
select trunc(some_date, 'HH24') 
from some_table
group by trunc(some_date, 'HH24');
```

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 datetime columns. One representing the beggining of the timespan and the other one, the end. Each hour within this timespan should be counted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(your_datetime_column, '%Y%m%d %H') AS `hourly`,
  COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(your_datetime_column, '%Y%m%d %H')
```

Comment: The problem is that I have 2 datetime columns. One representing the beggining of the timespan and the other one, the end. Each hour within this timespan should be counted.